# What could disable keyframes?

Tags: animation, keyframes

I have a situation where selected keyframes can't be deleted what could cause this?

[image]

[.blend](http://pasteall.org/blend/30357)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have set your keyframes to be 'Protected'. Click the padlock icon next to the 'Rotation' channel to unlock the keyframes so they can be edited.

[image]